# Elastic Heartbeat response check TCP error

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, tcp, health-monitoring

I have configured a simple [heartbeat 6.1](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/heartbeat/current/index.html) monitor:

```
heartbeat.monitors:
  - type: http
    schedule: '@every 10s'
    urls:
      - 'http://service/status'
    mode: all
    check:
      response:
        status: 200
```

which works. Monitor configuration also supports checking the content of the response by setting the key `check.response.body`

```
    ...
    mode: all
    check:
      response:
        status: 200
        body: UP
```

The service returns `UP` (checked with curl), but heartbeat detects the service as being down, due to the following error:

> read tcp x.y.z.a:port->b.c.d.e:80: use of closed network connection

Both the service and heartbeat are running as docker containers and share a common network (obviously, otherwise the first config would not work).

What could be the reason for the error? Is it a service problem (i.e. closing connection too early) or a problem with heartbeat? I have another service running (a simple node.js express application) which does not exhibit this behavior (so that would point to a service problem). How to troubleshoot?

**edit**

Running tcpdump/wireshark on the virtual docker network shows that the service properly responds to requests with `UP` every ten seconds (as configured in the heartbeat config). So apparently all requests are successful. Why is elastic heartbeat still complaning about closed connections?

Comment: Do you have anything in the logs? IMO "use of closed network connection" happens when the network connection runs into any error reading or writing to the underlying connection. In case there are no errors in the log, maybe [debug](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/heartbeat/current/enable-heartbeat-debugging.html) can show some relevant details.

Comment: I tried debug, but did not see anything interesting. I will try again, maybe I simply missed it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the same issue, but with the https checks. Seems like it's a bug in the Heartbeat that will be fixed in the Heartbeat version 6.5.0.

Here's the link of the issue on the github: https://github.com/elastic/beats/issues/8588
Pull request: https://github.com/elastic/beats/pull/8660

Comment: Ah, that would explain it. Thank you for your answer!